# Strange issue! encoding characters works only on body

Tags: php, sendmail

How to set characterset to UTF-8 that affects the subject of mail function with attachment,
Massive headache i'm getting,

i'm using this to send a french content (subject + body) + attached file.
The characters on teh body are okay and display well accented, but the accented chars on the subject are just a mess.

I'm getting the data via POST (except the attached file, allready has defined path on the server).

```
$email_from = "$Emp->Email";
$email_subject = $_POST['email_subject_posted'];
$email_message = "Nom: $Emp->Nom<br>";
$email_message .= "Prénom: $Emp->Prenom<br>";   
$email_message .= "Tel: $Emp->Mobile<br>";
$email_message .= "Email: $Emp->Email<br><br>";

$email_message .= stripslashes(strip_tags($lettre));
$email_message .= "<br><br>";
$email_message .= "Candidature envoyée avec mon compte Example.<br>";
$email_message .= "http://www.example.org<br>";
$email_message .= "1er Site de l’emploi en Algérie.";

$email_to = "$email_candidature";
$headers = "From: ".$email_from;
$file = fopen($CVfile,'rb');
$data = fread($file,filesize($CVfile));
fclose($file);
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
$email_message .= "\n\n";

$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$CVfile_type};\n" .
" name=\"{$CVfile_name}\"\n" .
//"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
//" filename=\"{$CVfile_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data .= "\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

$ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Any input is too much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had such a problem when my PHP file encoding wasn't similar to message encoding. Check the encoding of your PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this around your subject in the mail() function

```
'=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($email_subject).'?='
```

so it could look like

```
@mail($email_to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($email_subject).'?=', $email_message, $headers, '-f'.$email_from);
```